# Java Data PageRequest ColumnName and SortOrder in Strings

Tags: java, spring-data

How do I get Column Name and Order property strings in Java PageRequest ?

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
PageRequest pageRequest;
```

After I set it in constructor,

```
PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("ProductName").descending());
```

What properties should I use in Java to get values from PageRequest object ?

```
getPageRequest().getSort() ??
```

I will eventually put values in SQL with NamedParameter JDBC Template:

`select * from dbo.Product Order by @ColumnName @SortOrder` **Example**:
`select * from dbo.Order by ProductName desc`

Comment: How you are using pagerequest with jdbctemplate?

Comment: hi @AshishPatil namedParameter, I see need to extract the pagerequest column string after I set it here,  PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("ProductName").descending());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question properly , you want to extract column & order from PageRequest, then you can use something like below (getting Stream of Order, finding first element for extracting column and order details:

```
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("ProductName").descending());
Sort.Order order = page.getSort().get().findFirst().orElse(null);

if(order!=null) {
   String property = (null != order.getProperty()) ? order.getProperty() : null;   // returns you column name or else null
   String dir = order.getDirection().name();   //returns you Direction
}
```

Comment: @mattsmith5, I just used ternary operator here, but if you are still getting this warning, then you need to disable your warning as typically we won't see such warnings.